Not able to create organization namespace in Hyperledger Bevel using containerized ansible controller
I am following below link to deploy Hyperledger fabric DLT network using Hyperledger Bevel https://hyperledger-bevel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/docker-deploy/
I already have two existing organization (supply-chain & carrier-net) present in the network. When i try to run the ansible commands by following above link, almost all steps are successful but it failed to create namesapace for new organization (manufacturer-net). Below are the snapshots
Command -
useradmin@100:~/Docker/bevel$ docker run -it -v $(pwd):/home/bevel/ --network="host" ghcr.io/hyperledger/bevel-build:latest

As you can see in the file the subject syntax is not correctly autogenerated.


I tried with both the below syntax but every time is gives above error
subject: "''"'"'/C=US/ST=New York/L=New York/O=Store'"'"''"
subject: "''"'"'/C=US/ST=New York/L=New York/O=Store'"'"''"
